# How to check if it is possible to reach every element in an array via jumps of length m (modulo N)?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic

Given an array of length N, starting from the first position, how to check if it is possible to reach every position if it is only possible to jump m units.

EDIT:
I just found that it depends on the GCD of N and m. If the GCD is 1 (if they are coprime), then it is possible to reach every element, otherwise 'cycles' of their GCD will be formed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you elaborate on your question. Moreover, the body of your post should not be an extension of the title, rather the body should be self-sufficient i.e. one should be able to completely understand the question solely by reading the body text. Your problem statement isn't that clear either. Maybe you could also provide an example to explain what you are trying to ask?

Comment: $\gcd(a^n,b)\mid \gcd(a,b)^n$ is part of this. That and factoring out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are questioning the [Pisano Period.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisano_period)

Comment: Go to:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718940/logic-behind-pisano-period